# getting the username when using tomcat/JNDIRealm/active directory

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I am using tomcat/JNDIRealm and active directory.
I have it so tomcat prompts the user for username and password.
This all works and validates credentials against the AD

My question is how do i at the servlet/jsp level get the current users information (like full Name?) . I know nothing about AD, was just given the connect information to the ldap/AD and got it working.

i can get the username via

```
Principal p = request.getUserPrincipal();
System.out.println(p.getName());
```

This returns the username, is there anyway to get the users Full Name(not username)

Thanks for any help

Comment: So i have figured out how to get the username

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705246/getting-user-details-when-using-tomcat-realm

Comment: thanks, i tried to change my question before someone commented and pointed to this article